# WordPress online courses system

Tags: php

What exactly I need to learn to implement a system of online courses with modules like on the screenshot without plugins? When the user buys some course, it needs to be unlocked on his dashboard. Thank you for your help, it means a lot to me.
[image]

Comment: Your question is too broad to receive a good answer here. You may want to look into existing WordPress course plugins as one may meet your needs.

Comment: (If you really truly refuse to use a plugin - which goes against the WordPress way, as this is a lot of functionality - the alternative would be to build it all into a custom theme.)